# Is the following limit finite?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm not sure how to evaluate the following limit.

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{1}{1+\left (\frac{k}{n} \right)^{r}}
$$

I need to determine for which values of r the limit is finite. $r\geq 0$ for this problem.

The original form of the question was the following:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{n^{r-1}}{n^{r}+k^{r}}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{1}{1+(k/n)^r}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k'=1/n,2/n,\ldots}^{n}\frac{1}{1+(k')^r}\sim\int_{1/n}^{n}\frac{dx}{1+x^r}\rightarrow\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^r}
$$
when the improper integral converges.  This is the case only for $r>1$.